# Deleting Multiple Checkboxes Based on Selected Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have some Excel worksheets that use ActiveX checkboxes to control certain activity. I am looking for a method to delete the contents the column of the selected cell (both the text and the checkboxes). So far, I've been using the code below, but it has only deleted the checkbox in the cell below the active cell. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub DeleteJob1_Click()

If MsgBox("This will erase this job! Are you sure?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
Columns(ActiveCell.Column).Delete

Dim cb As CheckBox

For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If cb.TopLeftCell.Address = ActiveCell.Address Then cb.Delete
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
Sub DeleteJob1_Click()
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    If MsgBox("This will erase this job! Are you sure?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        If cb.TopLeftCell.Column = ActiveCell.Column Then cb.Delete
    Next
    Columns(ActiveCell.Column).Delete
End Sub
```